# java pattern and matcher

Tags: java, regex

I am using Pattern and Matcher classes from Java to parse a link file script.
The text I need is in the SECTIONS part:

```
SECTIONS
    {
        .text : {} > FAST_MEM /* Link all .text sections into ROM */
        .intvecs : {} > 0x0 /* Link interrupt vectors at 0x0 */
        .data : /* Link .data sections */
        {
            tables.obj(.data)
            . = 0x400; /* Create hole at end of block */
        } = 0xFF00FF00 > EEPROM /* Fill and link into EEPROM */
        ctrl_vars: /* Create new ctrl_vars section */
        {
            ctrl.obj(.bss)
        } = 0x00000100 > SLOW_MEM /* Fill with 0x100 and link into RAM */
        .bss : {} > SLOW_MEM /* Link remaining .bss sections into RAM */
    }
```

right now I am using

```
Pattern SectPattern = Pattern.compile("(SECTIONS\\{(.*)\\})");
```

and I want to extract the (.*) group but the result is not what I expected
Does anyone have any ideas of a better pattern to use?

Comment: so that means you might be having one or more SECTIONs in your file, correct?

Comment: Regular expressions are not the right choice for parsing matched, nestable braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will match and print the content inside SECTIONS `{` and `}`.:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("SECTIONS.*?\\{(.*)\\}", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sample);
matcher.find();

System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

where `sample` is your pattern sample. `Pattern.DOTALL` is required to handle line breaks correctly, the others should be self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have white spaces which you don't consider.
Try this:

```
"SECTIONS\\s*\\{(.*)\\}"
```

Notice that I also removed the outer group from the pattern (I don't see a reason for it).
In my example, after matching, use group 1.
Notice that this will work only if you do greedy matches (which is the case by default).